# Reduce NSManagedObjectContect save time

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am trying to make my algorithm faster as I am seeing long loading times. My app loads thousands of objects from an external database and then saves it on the device. I ran time profiler with my ipod touch and I saw that 17 seconds/26% of my loading time is spent executing NSManagedObjectContexts' save: function.

I am using one privacte nsmanagedobjectcontext and one persistant store coordinator.

What affects the time spent saving? If I save 1/10th of the data 10 times instead of all of the data once, which one is faster? What can I try to optimize the time spent saving?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: Describe how your code works in more detail. For example, do you call `save`: just once, or many times?

Comment: I do save several times. I fetch several batches of data and after each one I perform a save.

Comment: Saving it all at once is faster saving multiple times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. The best lever I have found for optimizing Core Data save times is indeed **finding the right batch size**.

As suggested by one commenter, the best way is to test it out. There are no definite rules because it really depends on the nature of your data, the size and number of the records etc.

Other strategies include using `@autorelease` pool(s) which will optimize memory usage and might improve performance as well.

Let us know your results!

Comment: I ended up doing some other clever changes to my database so I don't save as many objects anymore, but I am accepting your answer as it is probably would have helped